# How to add 2d points to a 3d scatterplot

Tags: r, matlab

I have a 3d scatterplot, and would like to display the 2d points onto the 3 planes (x,y), (x,z), and (y,z), as if they were shadows of the 3d data projected onto the planes. The left-hand figure is an example:

[image: http://www.doka.ch/Excel3Dscatterplot.htm]

Can this be achieved in R or Matlab? I have searched for code that can do this, but have not succeeded.

Comment: You will probably get more attention if you post some data-constructing R code. (This _is_ a coding site.) Should be fairly straightforward in R pkg:lattice or even in R base graphics.

Comment: Take the info in the Matlab-based answers below, port the code to R, and use `lattice` tools to plot the points, as DWin suggested.  Remember that your "shadow projection" points are simply points in 3D all of which have one axis' value set to zero (or max, depending on which face you're plotting to).

Comment: Got it, how simple. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for any 3D point

```
P = [x y z]
```

you can create the 3 shadows by creating 3 new points

```
p1 = [0 y z]
p2 = [x 0 z]
p3 = [x y 0]
```

So, in MATLAB, if you have a point cloud,

```
P_cloud = [...
    x1 y1 z1
    x2 y2 z2
    x3 y3 z3
    ...
];
```

Just plot

```
P_cloud_YZ = [...
    0 y1 z1
    0 y2 z2
    0 y3 z3
    ...
]; 

P_cloud_XZ = [...
    x1 0 z1
    x2 0 z2
    x3 0 z3
    ...
];  


P_cloud_XY = [...
    x1 y1 0
    x2 y2 0
    x3 y3 0
    ...
];
```

or, of course, re-use the same data

```
[P_cloud(:, [2 3]) zeros(size(P,1),1)]
[P_cloud(:, [1 3]) zeros(size(P,1),1)]
[P_cloud(:, [1 2]) zeros(size(P,1),1)]
```

Comment: Thanks Rody for your comments!

Answer (score 3):

After doing something like this:

```
figure
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(16);
x = [0.5*X(:); 0.75*X(:); X(:)];
y = [0.5*Y(:); 0.75*Y(:); Y(:)];
z = [0.5*Z(:); 0.75*Z(:); Z(:)];
scatter3(x,y,z)
```

you can just use the same figure and add some other plots to that:

```
hold on;
plot3(x,y,min(z)*ones(size(x)),'r+');
plot3(min(x)*ones(size(x)),y,z,'g+');
plot3(x,min(y)*ones(size(x)),z,'k+');
```

[image]